# Why do I get a Fatal Exception when I click on the button in my app that tells me if I should bring an umbrella today?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I am making an Android app using Java and I get a Fatal Exception when I click on the button.
The idea of the code is (using the jsoup library) to look up the chance to rain today and if the percentage is greater than 50% then it says yes and if it less than that it says no.
Here is the code

```
enterpackage com.example.doineedanumbrellatoday;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.*;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
TextView txtview;
Button button;

    public MainActivity() throws IOException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        txtview = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.button){
            Document doc= null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect("https://dalivali.bg/?location=222").timeout(6000).get();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        org.jsoup.select.Elements rain = doc.select("span.rain-num");
        //System.out.println(rain);
        char[] chars2 = rain.toString().toCharArray();
        StringBuilder chance = new StringBuilder();

        for(char c : chars2){
            if(Character.isDigit(c)){
                chance.append(c);
            }
        }
        if(Integer.parseInt(chance.toString())>=50) {
            txtview.setText("Yes");
        } else {
            txtview.setText("No");
        }
    }
}



}
```

Could someone tell me why I get an exception?

Comment: Here you got the runtime exception. Please share your error logs to find out the actual reason.

Comment: Always post the error, it tells you what you did wrong.  But here I can tell you-  you're doing networking on the main thread, which is illegal.  You need to launch anther thread to do networking on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Gabe Sechan* suggested, you have to run the connection of `JSoup` code in a background thread so your UI doesn't freeze and then you have to start a UI thread inside a background thread because you can't access views like `TextView` inside a background thread. So, you can start a background thread for the connection and UI thread for setting of texts like this:

```
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Document document = null;

                try {
                    document = Jsoup.connect("https://dalivali.bg/?location=222").timeout(6000).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                assert document != null;
                org.jsoup.select.Elements rain = document.select("span.rain-num");

                char[] chars2 = rain.toString().toCharArray();
                StringBuilder chance = new StringBuilder();

                for (char c : chars2) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        chance.append(c);
                    }
                }

                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(chance.toString()) >= 50)
                        txtview.setText("Yes");
                    else
                        txtview.setText("No");
                });
            }
        };

        thread.start();
```

Comment: so I put this code in the onClick method and now the app doesn't crash and I get no errors but the text on my textviev doesn't chage

Comment: use `log.d` inside `if else` statement to check.

Answer (score 1):

So I put the suggested code by @UndefinedBug1.0 and now I don't get errors but the text on my textview doesn't chage when I press the button

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view.getId()==R.id.button){
        final Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                Document document = null;

                try {
                    document = Jsoup.connect("https://dalivali.bg/?location=222").timeout(6000).get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                assert document != null;
                Elements rain = document.select("span.rain-num");

                char[] chars2 = rain.toString().toCharArray();
                StringBuilder chance = new StringBuilder();

                for (char c : chars2) {
                    if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
                        chance.append(c);
                    }
                }

                runOnUiThread(() -> {
                    if (Integer.parseInt(chance.toString()) >= 50)
                        txtview.setText("Yes");
                    else
                        txtview.setText("No");
                });
            }
        }.start();
    }}
```

Comment: You are missing `thread.start()` at the end.

Comment: Thank you a lot for the help, the app works now! Also sorry if my post is confusing it's my first time on stackoverflow

Comment: You did good. Glad it works :)

Comment: Could you [edit] this to contain the full answer to the question?